# Reading mail from system user

Tags: users, email

When I log into a server, I get `You have mail.`
With `alpine` and `sudo alpine` I've deleted all my and root's emails, but there is also a file `/var/spool/mail/smmsp`.  How can I check email from that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`smmsp` user/account most likely received only system notification emails. You can read such "text only emails" mailbox file in any text editor (e.g. vi).

Create email alias to redirect future emails:

- `smmsp` to `root`
- `root` to non privileged user/account